# error in connect to xmpp(openfire) server using java

Tags: java, xmpp, openfire, smack

I am new to XMPP. For a whole day I am stuck in connecting to my XMPP server (Openfire version 3.9.3) from Java. I am using the Smack (version 4.0.7) library. Here is simple code...

```
ConnectionConfiguration config =new ConnectionConfiguration("servername",5223);
XMPPTCPConnection connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(config);
    // Connect to the server
    try {
            connection.connect();
        connection.login("username", "password");

        }  catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XMPPException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SmackException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

But when I run this code this error is showing ...

```
org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NoResponseException
at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.throwConnectionExceptionOrNoResponse(XMPPConnection.java:548)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.throwConnectionExceptionOrNoResponse(XMPPTCPConnection.java:867)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.PacketReader.startup(PacketReader.java:113)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.initConnection(XMPPTCPConnection.java:482)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.connectUsingConfiguration(XMPPTCPConnection.java:440)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.connectInternal(XMPPTCPConnection.java:811)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.connect(XMPPConnection.java:396)
at test.third.<init>(third.java:19)
at test.third.main(third.java:34)
```

There may be a silly mistake and easy solution. I googled but somehow I am not getting the right solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public  void connectAndLogin( {

    connect();
    login();

}

private void connect() {
    /**
     * Set server configuration
     * 
     * connect to server    
     */
    setConfiguration();
    try {
        getConnection().connect();
    } catch (XMPPException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        setConnection(null);
    }
    }

    private void setConfiguration() {
        ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration(Constants.IP);
        SmackConfiguration.setPacketReplyTimeout(Constants.PACKET_TIME_OUT);
        System.out.println(SmackConfiguration.getVersion());
        config.setRosterLoadedAtLogin(false);
        // config.setCompressionEnabled(true);
        config.setVerifyChainEnabled(false);
        config.setReconnectionAllowed(true);
        config.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(false);
        config.setSecurityMode(SecurityMode.disabled);
        config.setDebuggerEnabled(false);
        connection = new XMPPConnection(config);
}

private void login() {
    if(getConnection()!=null){


    String USER_NAME="";

    String PASSWORD="";

    try {
        getConnection().login(USER_NAME,PASSWORD, Constants.RESOURCE);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using port 5222 instead of 5223.  That's the old SSL way which isn't typically used anymore.